# How to match parentheses group multiple times

Tags: regex

I need to convert this to this (below) or match the strings inside `<b>` and `</b>`.

```
<div>aaaaa<b>11111</b>bbbbb<b>2222</b>cccc<b>33333</b>ddd</div> -> 11111222233333
<div>cccc<b>222</b><b>333</b>xxxx</div> -> 222333
```

I tried using the regex below but I still cant find a way to match N times the parentheses group:

`<div.*?(<b>(.*?)<\/b>.*?)<\/div>`

Could you please help me?

Comment: This is not a regular grammar, so whatever you do it is probably gonna feel a bit awkward!

Comment: Are you sure? I just want to match a group multiple times, regex cant support it?

Comment: No, usually not. .NET and PyPi regex can do that. But parse HTML with the right tools, not regex.

Comment: It's not HTML, it can be any string. People here on SO treat other people like they are retard. I know I should not parse unsafe HTML like that... This is so clichè people telling the same thing

Comment: @Samul Yes, if you want to verify that multiple instances of correctly closed <b> it is going to be difficult with a regex alone. That said a full html parser, if overkill, isn’t really necessary either. Just like use regex to tokenize and a simple stack to go through the tokens.

Comment: @Samul also, it is not just because it looks like html. The classic example is checking if parentheses match, like `((()(()())))))(()()` regex literally can not.

Comment: If you want to remove everything from the string, besides any *non <* inside `<b>`...`</b>` you can replace [`.*?<b>([^<]*)<\/b>|.+` with `$1` or `\1`](https://regex101.com/r/s3wAiF/2) (capture of *first group*).

Comment: This is a more complicated thing that definitely can parse it http://lab.antlr.org/